How to get Apache Pheonix return HBase column family?
Using HBase to store data and Apache Pheonix as client to query, I found the output is weird.
Step 1: Load data to HBase
I load data from a DB to HBase using this format



Column Name
Column Family




usr_id
cf1


obj_id
cf2


Class_Name
cf3


Course_Mode
cf4



Step 2. Query Data from HBase using Pheonix
From Pheonix documentation, it is stated that we cannot directly query from existing HBase table but can create view on top of the existing table. Then, from created view, we can query from it.
So, I did as
CREATE VIEW "existing_table" ( pk VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, "cf1".VAL VARCHAR, "cf2".VAL VARCHAR, "cf3".VAL VARCHAR, "cf4".VAL VARCHAR );

The return output of the view is as below image which only "pk" column return all the column while other columns are null?

Below is the screenshot from HBase UI, for the table setttings.

My question is which part of the steps I did incorrectly? And what to be rectify?

Could you show the output for scanning the few rows of the HBase table. I think there might be some issues with loading the data to your HBase table

@vht981230 should I use Pheonix too? Or we can view from HBase UI?

I guess HBase UI is fine

@vht981230 I already edit my question, with screenshot of the table settings.

Is it possible to view the table content? It looks the screenshot HBase UI screenshot doesn't match with view screenshot

You should replace VAL in each column families with the column names you need to get values from
CREATE VIEW "existing_table" ( pk VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, "cf1"."usr_id" VARCHAR, "cf2"."obj_id" VARCHAR, "cf3"."Class_Name" VARCHAR, "cf4"."Course_Mode" VARCHAR );

